# Create Offline SQLite DataBase in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to create offline SQLite database for my send job module in android application. but the database in not created in DDMS .Tell me where I am wrong in the given code below.

```
    Fregmentsendjob.java

    public class FragmentSendJob extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
        // this Fragment will be called from MainActivity

        private Button submit,cancel;
        private EditText ename,mobno,picktime,unit,street,suburb,destination,fare,city;
        private Spinner state,group;
        private ViewGroup vgroup ;

            String name,pass;
            String status_key;
            private Typeface ftype;
            private static MyDialog dialog1;


            Bitmap bitmap1, bitmap2,bitmap3;
            Bitmap[] bitmap;
            String[] driver_details;
            private byte imageInByte1[],imageInByte2[],imageInByte3[] ;
            private Context mContext;


            public String advertisement_count;

         private String mename,mmobno,mpicktime,munit,mstreet,msuburb,mstate, msendjob,mcity,mdestination,mfare,mgroup,login_token;
       // private String sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate, ssendjob,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup,login_token;
        private static FragmentDialog dialog;
        //private  SendJobDataBase db; 
        private  PasswordDB db; 
        static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;

         private SharedPreferences pref1,pref;
        String latitude,longitude;
        public String job_id;



        public FragmentSendJob(){}

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
           {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sendjob_fragment, container, false);
            pref1=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("LocDetails", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            pref=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Driver", getActivity().MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            login_token=pref.getString("login_token","login_token"); 
            latitude = pref1.getString("latitude","latitude"); 
            longitude = pref1.getString("longitude","longitude"); 

            ename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ename);
            mobno  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobno);
            picktime  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.picktime);
            unit  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
            street  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.street);
            suburb  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.suburb);
            destination  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
            state = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.state);
            fare=(EditText)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.fare);
            group = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.group);
            city  = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.city);
            vgroup = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel); 
            submit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);


            submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        new SendJob().execute();
                  /*  Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),GetCurrentLocation.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 

                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+latitude+"***********");
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+longitude+"***********");*/


                    }

                });



            cancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0, count = vgroup.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
                        View view = vgroup.getChildAt(i);
                        if (view instanceof EditText) {
                            ((EditText)view).setText("");
                        }
                    }

                    }       
            });

            String[] mystate= new String[]{"New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland","Northern Territory","Western Australia","South Australia"};       
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.listrow, mystate);

            state.setAdapter(adapter);  

                    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    mcity =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();

                       String s1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                            if(s1.equals("New South Wales"))
                                city.setText("Sydney");
                            else if(s1.equals("Victoria"))
                                city.setText("Melbourne");
                            else if(s1.equals("Queensland"))
                                city.setText("Brisbane");
                            else if(s1.equals("Northern Territory"))
                                city.setText("Darwin");
                            else if(s1.equals("Western Australia"))
                                city.setText("Perth");
                            else if(s1.equals("South Australia"))
                                city.setText("Adelaide");

                                 }
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });


                    String[] mygroups= new String[]{"My Group","My Secondary group","Everyone"};
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapters = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                            R.layout.listrow, mygroups);
                    group.setAdapter(adapters);

                    group.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                        int pos, long arg3) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    msendjob = group.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                    //gender.setText(setgender);
                                }

                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
            return rootView;
           }



        private class SendJob extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

            @Override
            protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
            {
                ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
                {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    try 
                    {

                    System.out.print("***** login token *****"+login_token);
                    JSONObject job= new JSONObject();
                    mename = ename.getText().toString();
                    mmobno = mobno.getText().toString();
                    mpicktime = picktime.getText().toString();
                    munit = unit.getText().toString();
                    mstreet = street.getText().toString();
                    msuburb = suburb.getText().toString();
                    mstate = state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    mcity = city.getText().toString();
                    mdestination = destination.getText().toString();
                    mgroup = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    mfare = fare.getText().toString();

                    mename.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mmobno.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mpicktime.replace("" ,"%20");
                    munit.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mstreet.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mstate.replace("" ,"%20"); 
                    msuburb.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mcity.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mdestination.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mgroup.replace("" ,"%20");
                    mfare.replace("" ,"%20");

                         job.put("name",mename);
                         job.put("mobile_no",mmobno);
                         job.put("pickup_time",mpicktime);
                         job.put("unit_no",munit);
                         job.put("street_name",mstreet);
                         job.put("state",mstate);
                         job.put("suburb",msuburb);
                         job.put("city",mcity);
                         job.put("destination",mdestination);
                         job.put("group",mgroup);
                         job.put("fare",mfare);
                         job.put("latitude",latitude);
                         job.put("longitude",longitude);
                         job.put("status_key","2");
                         job.put("method","send_job");
                         job.put("login_token",login_token);

                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                        httppost.setEntity(se);
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        Log.i("response", data);

                        System.out.println("response "+data);
                        String call;
                        call = data;

                                    System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                                    Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                                    /*JSONObject jobId= jo.getJSONObject("id");  
                                    job_id=jobId.getString("id");*/


                                    if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                                dialog.dismiss();

                                /*   Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),HandleData.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("pickupsuburb", ssuburb);
                                        intent.putExtra("destination", sdestination);
                                        startActivity(intent);*/


                                             }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                        alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                                        alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                                        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int whichButton) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();


                                            }
                                        });
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                                        {
                                            public void run() 
                                            {
                                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                                alert.show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return params;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
                        {

                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                        }       
           }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }






    **SendJobDatabase.java**

     public class SendJobDataBase 
     {
        private static final  String DATABASE_NAME = "SENDJOB.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
        static final String TABLE_NAME = "jobsend";
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static Context context;
        static SQLiteDatabase db;
        private final ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

        OpenHelper helper;
        private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
```

//creation of string value and insert that string value into table name

```
        private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (mename,mmobno,mpicktime,munit,mstreet,msuburb,mstate,mcity,mdestination,mfare,mgroup) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

       // private static final String INSERT = "insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (sename,smobno,spicktime,sunit,sstreet,ssuburb,sstate,scity,sdestination,sfare,sgroup) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        protected static final String enternpw = null;
        public SendJobDataBase(Context context) {
        SendJobDataBase.context = context;
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(SendJobDataBase.context);
        SendJobDataBase.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.insertStmt = SendJobDataBase.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
        }
        //public long insert(String sename,String smobno,String spicktime,String sunit,String sstreet,String ssuburb,String sstate,String scity,String sdestination,String sfare,String sgroup) {
        public long insert(String mename,String mmobno,String mpicktime,String munit,String mstreet,String msuburb,String mstate,String mcity,String mdestination,String mfare,String mgroup) {

        this.insertStmt.bindString(1, mename);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(2, mmobno);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(3, mpicktime);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(4, munit);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(5, mstreet);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(6, msuburb);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(7, mstate);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(8, mcity);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(9, mdestination);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(10, mfare);
        this.insertStmt.bindString(11, mgroup);

        return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
        }

        public void deleteAll() {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
        }

        public List<String[]> selectAll()
        {
```

//create a function and apply cursor activity to perform on function

```
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        //Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","sename","smobno","spicktime","sunit","sstreet","ssuburb","sstate","scity","sdestination","sfare","sgroup" }, null, null, null, null, "sename asc");

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id","mename","mmobno","mpicktime","munit","mstreet","msuburb","mstate","mcity","mdestination","mfare","mgroup" }, null, null, null, null, "sename asc");
        int x=0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
           do {
            String[] b1=new String[]{cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),cursor.getString(11)};
            list.add(b1);
            x=x+1;
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
           cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
       }

         public ArrayList<member> getMembersList() {
            ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobsend WHERE ssendjob LIKE '%One%'" ;

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

             if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                member contact = new member();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
              contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));

              user.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
             }
                  cursor.close();
        return user;  

        }  


        public ArrayList<member> getMembersList2() {
            ArrayList<member> user = new ArrayList<member>();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobsend WHERE ssendjob LIKE '%Two%'" ;

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

             if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                member contact = new member();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
              contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));

              user.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
             }
                  cursor.close();
        return user;  

        }  

       public void delete(int rowId) {
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
       }

       private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        OpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sename TEXT, smobno TEXT,spicktime TEXT,spickaddr TEXT, sfair TEXT,ssendjob TEXT)");
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mename TEXT, mmobno TEXT,mpicktime TEXT,mpickaddr TEXT, mfair TEXT,msendjob TEXT)");


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
            {
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
             onCreate(db);
        }
       }

     public Cursor rawQuery(String selectQuery ,Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }    
    public static SendJobDataBase getDBAdapterInstance(FragmentGroups viewPassword) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public Object getenternpw() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public static Cursor getSinlgeEntry() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor cur =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE_NAME, null);
        // colName1+"='"+name+"'" ->  wherclause
        System.out.println("Record count are "+cur.getCount());
        return cur; 

    }



    static public void close() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    /* public SendJobDataBase open() throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }   */
     public SendJobDataBase getWritableDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }   


     public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        db.close();
        }


     public ArrayList<member> Get_Contacts() {

        try {
            user.clear();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM jobsend";

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                member contact = new member();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
              //  contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
             //   contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                // Adding contact to list
                user.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
        }

        return user;
       }

    }
```

Comment: whats is showing up in the logcat.. did u see any error in creating the table..

Comment: no there is no error.......but db is not created for send job

Comment: Show your complete DBHelper class